# Unit test for UWP app failed to run on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-10, uwp

I have trouble running unit test on one of my machine, the test app just shut down after few seconds. Here is the output show when debugging the test:

> Exception thrown at 0x7525D8A8 in UnitTestProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EETypeLoadException at memory location 0x0A17C5F0.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x7525D8A8 in UnitTestProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x7525D8A8 (KernelBase.dll) in UnitTestProject1.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x8007274C, 0x000000B9, 0x0EE4F6AC).
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> WinRT information: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Those exceptions is not related to my app at all, as my app dont need internet and the code in test method is not reached. They are from the test framework.

The same solution run test fine on every other machine (same Windows 10 build). I think the problem is that the system on troubled machine turn off some services required for unit testing. I cant find any thing related anywhere. What should I do to fix that, I dont want to re-install Windows.

Comment: I'm hitting the same problem, and reinstalling VS didn't fix it for me. But like you, it is working fine on another machine with exactly the same windows/sdk/visual studio versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up reinstall VS 2015 and the problem now gone.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the connection with the Test Emulator can't be established. When you build the TestApp make sure that you have set the Build configuration to Debug - Any CPU (not ARM)
Also, you shouldn't run the test project by hitting F5 but run the tests from the TestExplorer.